# solr case insensitivity

Tags: solr, case-sensitive

I have a problem where I am trying to search a field like 
`modelnumbers:"ModeL SX4"` I get no data. The field I am trying to make case insensitive looks like:

```
<arr name="modelnumbers">
<str>Model sX4</str>
</arr>
```

tried all the possible solutions like adding following in my schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" >
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"  ignoreCase="true"/>
   </analyzer>

   <analyzer type="query">

      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"  ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and using it with field like:

```
 <field name="modelnumbers" type="text"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true" />
```

Re-published my data so many times. Not working.
If I search for "model sX4", it works, but any other modification like "ModeL SX4" and all are failing. There is no consistency with the results. Also another field looks like: "24AAB3", if I try searching "24aAB3". this also doesnt work.

Please help.

Comment: found solution. Its better t use<tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>

Comment: copy field to lower-case, there was a question with a solution yesterday, have a quick search

Answer (score 1):

Your probem lies in the WordDelimiterFilterFactory. As it will split "ModeL SX4" into "M ode L SX 4" or something like that. So put LowerCaseFilterFactory right after tokenizer and you should be fine.

Comment: To that I will add one more suggestion, unless it's necessary, use one analyser for query and indexing. That would help with checking what is going wrong. And check up "admin/analysis.jsp" to see how your schema will behave on your set of data.